# Why is pdb showing Blank line or comment, but there is a line?

Tags: python, pdb

I'm trying to interactively run pdb on a remote system I don't own (I'm not sure if that's relevant), and it's behaving a bit differently than I expect. Listing the source shows there is clearly a line 22, but when I try to set the breakpoint, it tells me the line is blank. Fiddling a bit, I can get it to break on line 23, which is the line AFTER the one I want to break on. See terminal output below. I'm sure it's something dumb, but I'm at a loss.

EDIT: I just noticed something new.... I'm using conda, and if I use the base environment, I don't see this issue, but if I use an environment I created, it does.

```
(ecg) [tmhedr3@hmrihpcp03 ecg_analysis]$ python -m pdb rnn.py
> /home/tmhedr3/ecg_analysis/rnn.py(1)<module>()
-> import os
(Pdb) ll
  0     import os
  1  -> import glob
  2     import numpy as np
  3     import pandas as pd
  4     # import tensorflow as tf
  5     # import keras
  6     # from keras import layers
  7
  8     ages = open('ages.csv', 'r')
  9     lines = ages.readlines()
 10     n = len(lines)
 11
 12     data = np.ndarray((n, 5000, 12))
 13
 14     for i in range(n):
 15         li = lines[i].strip().split(sep=',')
 16         name = li[0]
 17         age = li[1]
 18
 19         leadData = np.loadtxt('./data/csv/' + name, skiprows=1, delimiter=',', usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11), dtype='int')
 20         data[i] = leadData
 21
 22     print(data.shape)
 23
(Pdb) b 22
*** Blank or comment
(Pdb) b 23
Breakpoint 1 at /home/tmhedr3/ecg_analysis/rnn.py:23
(Pdb) c
> /home/tmhedr3/ecg_analysis/rnn.py(23)<module>()
-> print(data.shape)
(Pdb)
```

Comment: Perhaps inconsistent new line types throwing off line counting?

Comment: Could there be a disagreement between the `.py` and `.pyc` files?

Comment: Hmm, I've been using vim to do the editing, and doing `:set lines` shows consistent newline types (i think). I also don't see a .pyc file in the directory, or when running pdb also.

I also notice (see above) that pdb seems to start on the second line instead of the first. Probably another symptom of the root cause...

Comment: Just checked on another system I use, the pdb line numbering starts from 1, not 0.

Comment: I'm using conda / miniforge with python version 3.10.12. Also noticing list vs longlist shows different line numbering. Short list shows it correctly. Might be related to https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/103225 but I'm still not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I tried executing dos2unix on the file for good measure, but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Noticed something new related to this.... conda (base) doesn't have this issue, but conda (my_env) does. So it might be something with conda.

Comment: PDB counts lines starting from "1", and  "ll" will usually show lines starting from "1" (I had just checked it here). Your listing starts counting numbering the first line as "0" instead, and that makes for the "off by one" problem you are facing. Perhaps you are using a custom (broken) debugger?

Comment: @jsbueno Yeah I noticed that... but pdb is a standard module in python, there is no separate version, it comes with python. In this case I'm using python 3.10.12 , while python 3.9.12 in my base env doesn't seem to have this issue

Comment: all you need is a rogue `pdb.py` file in the wrong place.

Comment: otherwise (and I really believe it can be "otherwise"), I have _no idea_ of how this could have happened there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is, you've been hit by this issue - https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/103319 - that is whyit only affects a few Python versions.

All it took for me to find was to open the `Lib/pdb.py` on cpython's source tree, look for "ll", and inspect visually the code from there - the issue itself is described as comments in the source code.

cPython's Lib/pdb.py

```
...
class Pdb(...):
    ...
    # [~ line 1992]
    def _getsourcelines(self, obj):
        # GH-103319
        # inspect.getsourcelines() returns lineno = 0 for
        # module-level frame which breaks our code print line number
        # This method should be replaced by inspect.getsourcelines(obj)
        # once this bug is fixed in inspect
        lines, lineno = inspect.getsourcelines(obj)
        lineno = max(1, lineno)
        return lines, lineno
```

Of course, changing the behavior of `inspect.getsourcelines` now to do as written would sure *break* a lot of code depending on its count-from-0 behavior. We are likely either stuck with this, unless someone adds an optional, defaulting to False, flag parameter for `getsourcelines` to start counting from 1.

Comment: OK thanks, in my case it's just an inconvenience. And I'm glad to hear it's not a symptom of something else that is wrong with my workflow.